# How to access uploaded images via URL in Django?

Tags: python, django, static, filesystems, ckeditor

I'm building a simple blog style web app for a friend. I am using CK editor and mostly stock Django 4.1. I'm stumped in how in what would be the best approach to let the creator to upload and serve images in their posts. CK editor allows you to add images via URL and I'd like for it to be possible to the creator to upload their files to the backend and would like to know if there are best practices when it comes to this.

Right now I have this:

```
def editor_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = UploadFileForm
        path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'files')
        files = os.listdir(path)
        return render(request, 'upload.html', {"form": form, "files": files})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        file = request.FILES['file']
        title = str(file)
        if form.is_valid():
            path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'files')
            fs = FileSystemStorage(location=path)
            fs.save(title, file)

        return redirect('/editor/upload')


def open_file(request, file_name):
    print(file_name)
    return render(request, 'file.html', {"file": file_name})
```

in editor_upload, the user can see what files there are in the specified folder (but cannot access them yet) and there is the logic to upload new pictures to the folder. The problem comes now: I don't know how to properly access them.

In open_file, the request receives the name of the file and gives it to the HTML templating. This does not work because the template looks into the project folder and not into the root static folder. I must admit I'm a bit lost with how the static folders in Django works because I've been mostly utilizing just the project static folder. Also, I don't think this would work for CK editor to grab the image.

Any ideas on how I could solve this? I also tried doing it by uploading the image to a database but I had kind of the same problem. I need to somehow generate an URL to pass into CK editor. Many thanks!

Comment: You should use MEDIA_ROOT for uder uploaded files. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/files/

Comment: The question remains, however. I'm sending the files to my media folder now, but I still don't know how to properly access them. image.url actually gets me the url to the media folder but going to it gives me a broken image.

Comment: any errors ? Provide also your settings and urls code.

Comment: Without further information we can not help. Serving files locally may also be different than serving them from a server.